# Does SSMS use ODBC?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, connectivity, odbc

I am running SSMS V18.2 and connecting to SQL 2008 - 2019 instances.

I am researching various multiple subnet connection scenarios.  I learned that ODBC 13.1+ includes [`TransparentNetworkIPResolution`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-transparent-network-ip-resolution?view=sql-server-ver15) which alters the way connections are made with multiple subnets.

My computer has several different drivers on it.

[image: Screenshot of 5 different drivers]

I want to know which (*if any*) of these SSMS is using for direct connections to SQL instances in my network.

I have looked at tools > options and I don't see anything that gives me an option to change what driver is used to connect.

When I Google, I get results about using ODBC for Linked servers.

Does SSMS use ODBC for direct connects?

If so can I select which one it uses?

**Edit** There is a comment and an answer indicating SSMS does not use ODBC, based on my continuing research it I think it uses the `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` in the screen shot above.

Looking at [Using Connection String Keywords with SQL Server Native Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) it seems like you can connect with the driver of you choice using the keyword `Driver` I am still researching how that might work.

**Edit2** Actually it looks like [(*see related*)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/256526/21924)
  the driver is not one of those in the screen shot, nor can you use the keyword `driver` to change drivers.

Comment: This query from an SSMS query window returns `.Net SqlClient Data Provider`: `SELECT client_interface_name FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID;`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SSMS doesn't use ODBC drivers to connect to SQL Server databases. It uses the .Net Framework driver.
You cannot choose which driver it uses as it is hard-coded in the application. But why would you need to choose another one?

Linked servers are another thing. It is your DB Server itself connecting to another server. If it is SQL Server, it will use its native driver. It if it another DB Engine type, it will then ask you which driver to use. And this is where you select your ODBC driver for MySQL, Oracle, Postgres or other.

Comment: Per security scans, I needed to upgrade odbc drivers on servers and noticed connections from SSMS to the sql server logs use odbc.  I removed version 13 and added 18, but now get:
Severity: 16 Error:0, OS: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: @NicholasMcQuillen if you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Yes, I'm quite familiar with knowing how to ask a question on stack, thanks.  My comment was a statement providing evidence SSMS did use an ODBC connection via the error.